# Cin used on character arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, input

In C++ , Is this a valid/efficient way to input a series of characters ?
As in :

```
char abc[100]; 
cout<<"Enter your address:";  
cin>>abc;
```

[This](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/) says :

> However, cin extraction always considers spaces (whitespaces, tabs, new-line...) as terminating the value being extracted, and thus extracting a string means to always extract a single word, not a phrase or an entire sentence.

Since the above statement is given for Strings and not character arrays , I am confused .
Will this code work properly ?

Note : I am using TurboC++

Comment: which version of turbo c++?  (the 2006 version is quite different to the 1992 version)

Comment: Yes, but... why would you use a `char*` to begin with?  Use `std::string` and avoid silly buffer overruns.  If you want to read a line, don't use character based input, use `getline`

Comment: @EdS. I am aware of getline() but wanted to know whether just cin>>abc; works well . So even for character arrays , only one word will be inputted by this method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to read only non-whitespace characters, you can use:

```
char abc[100]; 
cout<<"Enter your address:";  
cin >> abc;
```

However, that is risky. If the sequence of non-whitespace characters consists of 100 or more characters, you will run into the problem of accessing memory out of bounds, which will lead to undefined behavior.

If you want to read everything up to a the newline character, you can use:

```
char abc[100]; 
cout<<"Enter your address:";  
cin.getline(abc, 100);
```

This has the added advantage that it will not read more than 99 character, saving the last space for the null terminator.

More details on `istream::getline()` can be found at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline.

Comment: Yes , I am aware of this but I wanted to know specifically for cin>>abc;  Why would this be wrong ?

Comment: @eatq, It will be the wrong function to use to read white space characters  into `abc`. If you wanted to read just non-white space characters, it would be the right function to use.

Comment: Just the first set of non-white space characters , right ?

Comment: If I use just cin>>abc; and the user input is "XYZ pqr" , will XYZpqr get stored (as you say that non-white chars get inputted) or just  XYZ (as @Vlad says in his answer ) ?

Comment: When the user input is "XYZ ptr", only "XYZ" will be stored in `abc` because the next character is a whitespace character.

Comment: Okay , thanks . And the link had shown an example of this type : 'string abc; cin>>abc; '  .. Same logic over here too right ?

Comment: @eatq, which link are you talking about?